# Python: Count element matches in arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, compare

```
a = [ ['Active', '1.0', '0.0', 'Business', 'London'], ['Active', '0.0', '0.0', 'Business', 'Scotland'] ]

b = ['Active', '0.0', '0.0', 'Retail', 'London']
```

Desired Output: `[3, 3]` because 3 columns match for`a[row 0] and b, and 3 columns match for a[row 1] and b.

I want to count the number of element matches for each row in a compared with b. Each column is a variable so order matters. This is done for a big array so performance also matters.

I tried `[sum(x==y) for x,y in zip(a,b)]` but this isn't right

Answer (score 1):

You got the idea, but there is a problem in the code: `sum(x==y)` sums single boolean values instead of the list of bools. A nested list should be what you are looking for. Here is a way to do it:

```
[sum([x==y for x,y in zip(a_element, b)]) for a_element in a]
```

Output: `[3, 3]`